# Prove for cohomology theory $E^\bullet$, there is an isomorphism $E^\bullet(X,A) \stackrel{\simeq}{\longrightarrow} E^\bullet(X \cup Cone(A), \ast)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is a question from the proof for Lemma 2.8 of (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+%28Eilenberg-Steenrod%29+cohomology).

Given an cohomology theory $E^\bullet$ and $A \hookrightarrow X$, the lemma claims that $E^\bullet(X,A) \stackrel{\simeq}{\longrightarrow} E^\bullet(X \cup Cone(A), \ast)$, where $Cone(A)$ is the reduced cone of $A$.

(I think $Cone(A)$ in this lemma is reduced, because it is then used to prove proposition 3.2, where an unreduced cohomology theory can give a reduced cohomology theory.)

According to the proof of the lemma, we define $U = (Cone(A)-A \times \{0\}) \hookrightarrow Cone(A)$, and then we try to use excision axiom to show $E^\bullet (X\cup Cone(A), Cone(A)) \stackrel{\simeq}{\longrightarrow} E^\bullet (X\cup Cone(A)-U, Cone(A)-U)$.

The question that confuses me is: The excision axiom requires $\overline{U} \subset Int(Cone(A))$, which seems quite strange and not always satisfied when $Cone(A)$ is reduced. For example, when the basepoint $*$ is on the boundary of $A$, $\overline{U}$ can contain $*$ while $*$ is not in $Int(Cone(A))$. So how to deal with it？

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no basepoints given for $(X,A)$ in the lemma, so they are definitely not using the reduced cone. If one is trying to use reduced cones in the axioms of a reduced cohomology theory, one must restrict to well pointed spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lemma deals with an *unreduced  cohomology theory*. No basepoints are involved on this case, but unfortunately the lemma does not make precise what is meant by $Cone(A)$ in this case. Actually $X \cup Cone(A)$ denotes the [mapping cone](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/mapping+cone) of the inclusion $i: A \hookrightarrow X$. Writing $X \cup Cone(A)$ is perhaps a bit sloppy because it suggests that $X \cup Cone(A)$ is an "ordinary union" of $X$ and $Cone(A)$ and does not make explicit that a gluing process in involved here. In fact $X \cup Cone(A)$ is the adjunction space obtained frm $X$ by attaching $Cone(A)$ via the obvious embedding of its base $A \times \{0\}$ into $X$. However, $X \cup Cone(A)$ indeed contains a copy of the unreduced cone $Cone(A)$ as a subspace.

The proof is based on the excision of some $U \subset Cone(A)$ to get an isomorphism
$$\iota^* : E^n(X \cup Cone(A), Cone(A)) \to E^n((X \cup Cone(A)) \setminus
U, Cone(A)\setminus U) . \tag{1}$$
Unforunately $U = Cone(A) \setminus A \times \{0\}$ does not work because  $\overline U = Cone(A)$ which is in general not contained in $Int(Cone(A))$ (it may only be in some special cases).

Instead we take $U = Cone(A) \setminus A \times [0,1/2]$; then $\overline U \subset Int(Cone(A))$ and we see that $(1)$ is an isomorphism.

The space $(X \cup Cone(A)) \setminus U$ is a copy of the mapping cylinder of the inclusion $i$. Let $r : (X \cup Cone(A)) \setminus U \to X$ be a strong deformation retraction. This gives a homotopy equivalence of pairs $r : ((X \cup Cone(A)) \setminus U, Cone(A) \setminus U) \to (X,A)$. Thus
$$r^* : E^n(((X \cup Cone(A)) \setminus U, Cone(A) \setminus U) \to E^n(X,A) \tag{2}$$
is an isomorphism which shows that we get an isomorphism
$$E^n(X \cup Cone(A), Cone(A)) \to E^n(X,A) .$$
In a final step we get an isomorphism
$$\phi^* : E^n(X \cup Cone(A), Cone(A)) \to E^n(X \cup Cone(A),*) \tag{3]$$
where $*$ is any point of $Cone(A)$, for example its tip. This isomorphism is induced by the inclusion of pairs $\phi : (X \cup Cone(A), *) \to (X \cup Cone(A), Cone(A))$. This is not a homotopy equivalence of pairs, but the "absolute map" $X \cup Cone(A) \to X \cup Cone(A)$ is the identity and the "restricted map" $* \to Cone(A)$ is a homotoppy equivalence. The long exact sequences of the pairs $(X \cup Cone(A), *)$ and $(X \cup Cone(A), Cone(A))$ are connected by $\phi$ and its restrictions, hence the five lemma shows that $(3)$ is an isomorphism.

Let me finally remark that the I do not recommend nLab as a good source for generalized cohomology. Better consult the references in the nLab-article.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. But if I take X∪Cone(A) to be unreduced mapping cone, I can't prove the exactness axiom in proposition 3.2. (Proposition 3.2 is theorem 12.1.12 on the textbook Algebraic Topology - Homotopy written by Robert Switzer, where the mapping cone should be reduced, but he omitted the proof of this theorem.)

Comment: @ZYEric In my copy of Switzer there is no Theorem 12.1.12. nLab refers to Switzer 7.34. Also Switzer makes the mistake of confusing reduced and unreduced cones. In Switzer's setup it is a serious problem. He considers reduced (co)homology theories on the category of **all** pointed spaces, and working with the reduced cone in $X \cup Cone(A)$ does not produce the desired isomorphism unless the basepoint $x_0$ is non-degenerate in $A$ (since then reduced cone and unreduced cone with basepoint $(x_0,0)$ are pointed homotopy equivalent). In the nLab-setup it is okay since we work with CW-spaces.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake I made. The theorem 12.1.12 I mentioned is from section 12.1 of Algebraic topology from a homotopical viewpoint, which also seem to have incorrect setup as Switzer 7.34. So the definition of reduced (co)homology theories should be modified if we want to work on the category of all pointed spaces. Is there an elegent way to do this?

Comment: @ZYEric No, the definition of reduced (co)homology theories is the standard one. But we must accept that reduced and unreduced theories cannot be transformed into each other without additional assumptions on the categories on which they are defined or without assuming additional axioms (like the weak homotopy equivalence axiom).

Comment: One more remark: The definition of unreduced cohomology in nLab has to be taken with care. It works with the category of CW-pairs, so the excision axiom cannot be used fo arbitrary $U$ with $\overline U \subset Int(A)$. It only works if $(X \setminus U, A\setminus U)$ is again a CW-pair.